# JSF 2.0: Why object in my list (except the last one) cannot be updated

Tags: java, list, jsf-2

In my code, I have the following objects to implement a shopping cart:

```
public class CartItem {
    ...
    public int id;
    public int quantity;
    ...
}

public class Partner {
    ...
    public List<CartItem> listOfItems;
    ...
}

public class Cart implements Serializable {
    ...
    private List<Partner> listOfPartners;
    ...
}
```

In the ViewCart.xhtml page, I list the items as following:

```
...
<ui:repeat value="#{cartManagedBean.cart.listOfPartners}" var="p">
    <ui:repeat value="#{p.listOfItems}" var="i">
        <h:form>
            ...
            <h:inputText size="3" value="#{i.quantity}" />

            <h:commandButton value="Update" />
            ...
        </h:form>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
...
```

And this is my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CartManagedBean {
    ...
    private Cart cart;
    ...
}
```

All the getters and setters methods are properly done. Hence, I expected that when I click the update button, the quantity of the corresponding Item would be updated. However, when I test the function, only the last item in the list can be updated.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on how I should tackle this problem.

**UPDATE:** I managed to make it work by replacing `ui:repeat` with `h:dataTable`. I think my knowledge of `ui:repeat` should be wrong somewhere. When I was using `ui:repeat`, I saw that the HTML generated was something like:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="jdt:51;jdt52" />
    ...
</form>
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="jdt:51;jdt52" />
    ...
</form>
```

In other words, all the Items were generated with the same ID. I even tried to make the ID of the input for quantity unique by appending the unique ID of each item to the ID of the input as following:

```
<h:inputText id="quantity#{i.id}" size="3" value="#{i.quantity}" />
```

However, in the HTML result, I saw that the ID was something like:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="jdt:51;jdt52;quantity203" />
    ...
</form>
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="jdt:51;jdt52;quantity203" />
    ...
</form>
```

In other words, the ID of the 1st Item was repeated for all subsequent items. Even though I haven't fully understood how variables are updated with new values, I think this is the reason why only the last item can be updated.

I'd be very grateful if someone could explain this further for me so that I won't make the same mistake again =).

Comment: `<h:commandButton value="Update" />` here, are you calling some method?

Comment: @BheshGurung: no, I am not calling any method here. I just want to update the variables without doing any additional things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Mojarra. The `<ui:repeat>` is [totally broken](http://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JAVASERVERFACES%20AND%20%28summary%20~%20ui%3arepeat%20OR%20description%20~%20ui%3arepeat%20OR%20comment%20~%20ui%3arepeat%29) in Mojarra. I can reproduce your problem even on the latest Mojarra 2.1.4. It however works 100% when using [MyFaces 2.1.3](http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html). I've reported it to the Mojarra guys as [issue 2243](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2243).

You have 3 options:

- Replace Mojarra by MyFaces.
- Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`. This only works if the `<c:forEach>` is not by itself inside some `UIData` component.
- Use an `UIData` component instead of `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: As always, I think you shot right at my problem. I am indeed using Mojarra at the moment. However, it's too late for me to change already. I have just submitted my Project yesterday. I will note this for future Project =].